# Wordpress Booking Calendar JS script conflict

Tags: javascript, plugins, wordpress, conflict

I'm using the latest version of Wordpress and WP Booking Calendar plugin on http://www.caroline-cottage.co.uk/booking-form/ [1](http://www.caroline-cottage.co.uk/booking-form/)

Although the calendar and form elements work great in isolation as a widget I cannot get them to display on the same page due to what I assume is a JS script error/conflict. However, IE and Firefox debuggers don't show any issues.

I've tried reinstalling and deactivating all plugins.

Any ideas how to resolve??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Upon reading the T&C's of the WP Booking Calendar plugin again I realised you can only display two elements (1 calendar, 1 form) on 1 page using the free version of the plugin so I needed to remove the widget version in the header to "fix" the 'calendar loading...' issue  :-)